# how to search filter multipe relation table and groupping in yii2

Tags: php, model, yii2, search-engine, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables like `ridersPoint (id, nameRider, serie_id, point)` and `series (serie_id, nameSerie, location, date, season_id)` and `season (season_id, nameSeason, year)`.
Attribute `serie_id` in `riderPoint` table have relation with `serie_id` in `series` table, and Attribute `season_id` in `series` table have relation with `season_id` in `season` table.
How to make search by `season_id` in `riderPoint`? And how to groupping point when have data table in the same `season`?
Please help me..

Comment: Where do you want to do this, in a gridview.. in a sqlCommand.. ?

Comment: In gridview @scaisEdge

Comment: Example i have two series_id in the same season. In grid view for grouping will show `id, nameRider, point 1, point 2`

Answer (score 3):

Search (filter  and sort) for related field in gridview is base an a series of action.. you can find some sample in this doc

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

in brief..

- In your model  define your active relation in (main/pivot) model and add the getter for related field
- In your modelSearch in your dataProvider  add the var fo related field, set the proper sort for sorting  by new related field, add the relation in search function and adding proper filter in modelSearch condition
- Add the new attribute to the gridview..

Take a deep look to the scenario 2 in the link provided.. and you can find what you need

Comment: And how to grouping column please. I dont know how to start it

Comment: For grouping you mean concatenation  like Name + Surname?

Comment: I have see your comment in question.. for grouping you mean show the result of series in separated column?

Comment: Yes its true. The point for each series will grouping on same name rider

Comment: In this case it is possible to manage in a not too complicatedway  a fixed number of series. (fixed number of columns), while for the dynamic columns management with gridview i'm not able to give you suggestions.