# PHP, Yii2 GridView filtering on relational value php entity-relationship yii2

Tags: join, yii2, relational-database

Following on from this:

`Yii2` how does search() in SearchModel work?

I would like to be able to filter a `GridView` column of relational data. This is what I mean:

I have two tables, `TableA` and ``. Both have corrTableBesponding models generated using `Gii`. TableA has a foreign key to a value in TableB, like this:

```
TableA
attrA1, attrA2, attrA3, attrA4(TableB.attrB1)

TableB
attrB1, attrB2, attrB3

Joining table A & B : TableC
attrC1, attrC2, attrA4
```

`attrA1` and `attrB1` are the primary keys of their corresponding tables.

Now, I have a Yii2 GridView of attrA2, attrA3 and attrB2. I have a working filter on attrA2 and attrA3 so that I can search on column values. I also have a working sort for these two columns too - by just clicking on the column header. I would like to be able to add this filtering and sorting on attrB2 too.

Comment: Please add real code and clarify what do you want to see in result exactly.

Comment: This coulld be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916480/how-to-search-filter-multipe-relation-table-and-groupping-in-yii2

Answer (score 0):

First:
In index.php in 'columns' remove attrA4 and add this to get Search filed:

```
[
  'attribute'=>'TableB',
  'value'=>'TableB0.attrB2', // this is get function from TableA model class                
  ],
```

Second: 
In TableASearch class remove from rules() function attrA4 which is under 'integer' and add this into second array right there under 'safe' .

Third:
In TableASearch class in search function add:

```
  $query->joinWith('TableB0');
```

Next from: $query->andFilterWhere([ ... remove parameter:

```
'attrA4' => $this->attrA4,
```

and add in second $query->andFilterWhere([  add parameter at the end:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'TableB.attrB2', $this->attrA4]);
```

You have good basic things on DoingITeasyChannel on youtube.

Good luck !